# Translate SingleSelect Items

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, xliff

We have created a TYPO3 extension which renders OpenGraph meta tags. For any page, the editor can set specific parameters including the type. 
For the type, we added a single select which holds all possible types as a static item list. As we want to provide the labels in the select in English and German we translated them in separated XLIFF files. For the field labels, this works perfect, but in the select field, just the translation keys appear.

We have checked the keys 3 times and found no misspelling in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2019-06-11T11:19:00Z" product-name="ige_opengraph">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tab.opengraph" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>OpenGraph</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_image" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>OpenGraph Image &quot;og:image&quot;</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_video" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>OpenGraph Video &quot;og:video&quot;</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_text" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>OpenGraph Text &quot;og:description&quot;</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_title" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>OpenGraph Title &quot;og:title&quot;</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_pagename" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>OpenGraph Page Name &quot;og:site_name&quot;</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_url" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>OpenGraph URL &quot;og:url&quot;</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_type" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>OpenGraph Type &quot;og:type&quot;</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_locale" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>OpenGraph Locale &quot;og:locale&quot;</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_activities_section" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Activities</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_activities" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Activities</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_sport" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Sports</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_business" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Business</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_bar" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Bar</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_company" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Company</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_cafe" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Cafe</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_hotel" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Hotel</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_restaurant" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Restaurant</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_groups" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Groups</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_cause" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Cause</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_sports_league" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Sports league</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_sports_team" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Sports team</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_organizations" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Organizations</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_band" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Band</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_government" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Government</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_non_profit" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Non profit</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_school" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>School</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_university" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>University</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_people" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>People</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_actor" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Actor</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_athlete" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Athlete</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_author" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Author</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_director" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Director</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_musician" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Musician</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_politician" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Politician</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_public_figure" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Public figure</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_places" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Places</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_city" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>City</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_country" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Country</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_landmark" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Landmark</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_state_province" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>State province</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_entertainment" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Entertainment</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_album" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Album</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_book" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Book</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_drink" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Drink</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_food" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Food</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_game" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Game</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_product" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Product</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_song" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Song</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_movie" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Movie</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_tv_show" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>TV show</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_websites" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Websites</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_blog" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Blog</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_website" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Website</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_article" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Article</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" target-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2019-06-11T11:19:00Z" product-name="ige_opengraph">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tab.opengraph" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>OpenGraph</source>
                <target>OpenGraph</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_image" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>OpenGraph Image &quot;og:image&quot;</source>
                <target>OpenGraph Bild &quot;og:image&quot;</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_video" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>OpenGraph Video &quot;og:video&quot;</source>
                <target>OpenGraph Video &quot;og:video&quot;</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_text" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>OpenGraph Text &quot;og:description&quot;</source>
                <target>OpenGraph Text &quot;og:description&quot;</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_title" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>OpenGraph Title &quot;og:title&quot;</source>
                <target>OpenGraph Titel &quot;og:title&quot;</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_pagename" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>OpenGraph Page Name &quot;og:site_name&quot;</source>
                <target>OpenGraph Seitenname &quot;og:site_name&quot;</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_url" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>OpenGraph URL &quot;og:url&quot;</source>
                <target>OpenGraph URL &quot;og:url&quot;</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_type" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>OpenGraph Type &quot;og:type&quot;</source>
                <target>OpenGraph Typ &quot;og:type&quot;</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_locale" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>OpenGraph Locale &quot;og:locale&quot;</source>
                <target>OpenGraph Lokalisierung &quot;og:locale&quot;</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_activities_section" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Activities</source>
                <target>Aktivitäten</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_activities" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Activities</source>
                <target>Aktivitäten</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_sport" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Sports</source>
                <target>Sport</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_business" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Business</source>
                <target>Geschäfte</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_bar" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Bar</source>
                <target>Bar</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_company" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Company</source>
                <target>Firma</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_cafe" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Cafe</source>
                <target>Cafe</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_hotel" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Hotel</source>
                <target>Hotel</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_restaurant" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Restaurant</source>
                <target>Restaurant</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_groups" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Groups</source>
                <target>Mannschaften</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_cause" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Cause</source>
                <target></target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_sports_league" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Sports league</source>
                <target>Mannschaftssport</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_sports_team" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Sports team</source>
                <target>Teamsport</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_organizations" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Organizations</source>
                <target>Firmen</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_band" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Band</source>
                <target>Band</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_government" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Government</source>
                <target>Staat</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_non_profit" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Non profit</source>
                <target>Ehrenamtlich</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_school" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>School</source>
                <target>Schule</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_university" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>University</source>
                <target>Universität</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_people" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>People</source>
                <target>Personen</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_actor" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Actor</source>
                <target>Schauspieler</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_athlete" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Athlete</source>
                <target>Athlet</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_author" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Author</source>
                <target>Autor</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_director" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Director</source>
                <target>Regiesseur</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_musician" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Musician</source>
                <target>Musiker</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_politician" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Politician</source>
                <target>Politiker</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_public_figure" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Public figure</source>
                <target>Öffentliche Person</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_places" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Places</source>
                <target>Orte</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_city" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>City</source>
                <target>Stadt</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_country" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Country</source>
                <target>Land</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_landmark" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Landmark</source>
                <target>Denkmahl</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_state_province" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>State province</source>
                <target>Provinz</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_entertainment" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Entertainment</source>
                <target>Unterhaltung</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_album" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Album</source>
                <target>Album</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_book" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Book</source>
                <target>Buch</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_drink" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Drink</source>
                <target>Getränk</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_food" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Food</source>
                <target>Essen</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_game" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Game</source>
                <target>Spiel</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_product" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Product</source>
                <target>Produkt</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_song" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Song</source>
                <target>Lied</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_movie" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Movie</source>
                <target>Film</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_tv_show" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>TV show</source>
                <target>TV Show</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_websites" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Websites</source>
                <target>Webseiten</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_blog" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Blog</source>
                <target>Blog</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_website" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Website</source>
                <target>Webseite</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_article" xml:space="preserve" approved="yes">
                <source>Article</source>
                <target>Artikel</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

```
'neutralized' => array (        
        'exclude' => 1,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_opengraph_type',        
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'selectSingle',
            'items' => array (
                array('', ''),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_activities_section', '--div--'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_activities', 'activity'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_sport', 'sport'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_business', '--div--'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_bar', 'bar'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_company', 'company'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_cafe', 'cafe'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_hotel', 'hotel'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_restaurant', 'restaurant'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_groups', '--div--'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_cause', 'cause'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_sports_league', 'sports_league'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_sports_team', 'sports_team'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_organizations', '--div--'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_band', 'band'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_government', 'government'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_non_profit', 'non_profit'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_school', 'school'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_university', 'university'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_people', '--div--'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_actor', 'actor'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_athlete', 'athlete'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_author', 'author'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_director', 'director'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_musician', 'musician'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_politician', 'politician'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_public_figure', 'public_figure'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_places', '--div--'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_city', 'city'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_country', 'country'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_landmark', 'landmark'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_state_province', 'state_province'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_entertainment', '--div--'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_album', 'album'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_book', 'book'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_drink', 'drink'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_food', 'food'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_game', 'game'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_product', 'product'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_song', 'song'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_movie', 'movie'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_tv_show', 'tv_show'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_websites', '--div--'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_blog', 'blog'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_website', 'website'),
                array('LLL:EXT:ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:pages.tx_igeopengraph_type.div_article', 'article')
            ),
            'size' => 1,    
            'maxitems' => 1,
        )
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

For field labels you use LLL file

`ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf`

For your select labels you use another LLL file

`ige_opengraph/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf`

Just ensure you use correct LLL file, or move your translation to the given LLL file as defined in your TCA configuration.

Comment: We have tested it with locallang_db.xlf and locallang.xlf and it didn't work.

Comment: Is it TYPO3 v7.6?